# c# equation is drawing a hole in the graph

Tags: c#

```
        for (double x=0;x<=7D;x+=.01D)
        {
            b = 1.771289; c = 2.335719; d = 0.5855771; g = 4.4990302; h = 4.3369349; k = 0.67356705;
            y = b * Math.Exp(-(0.5 * (Math.Pow(((x - c) / d), 2)))) +
                g * Math.Exp(-(0.5 * (Math.Pow(((x - h) / k), 2))));
            qResults.Rows.Add(x, y);
        }
```

the graph is good but it draws a hole in the peek.i am using mschart:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/graph1v.png/

i would like to know whether the hole is a problem with my syntax?

Comment: What are you using to draw the graph?

Comment: @howard make that into an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your y-axis range is bounded by the maximum value, but the very point falls exactly outside the plotting range.

One solution is to add a small amount to the axis range such that all points fall clearly inside the plotting space.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the max `y` range for the graph a little over the max value. If the max value is 4.5 then make the graph y-axis limit equal to 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your syntax, that really should be a smooth curve. I stuck it into matlab just to be certain.